# What's the principle of web scanning softwares?

Tags: network-scan

How can it scan all available pages automatically?

One way I can think of is to scan it recursively from the home page.

But it won't be able to scan out the back end CMS .

So how do those scanning tools work?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stupid web crawler:

Start by creating an array to store links, and putting one URL in there yourself. Create a second empty array to store visited URLs. Now start a program which does the following.

1. Read and remove first item in the link array
2. Download webpage at that URL
3. Parse HTML for link tags, add all links found to the link array
4. Add the webpage URL to the visited URL array
5. Goto 1

If you assume that every page on the web is reachable by following some number of random links (possibly billions), then simply repeating steps 1 through 4 will eventually result in downloading the entire web. Since the web is not actually a fully connected graph, you have to start the process from different points to eventually reach every page.

Comment: That's what I mentioned above,the recursive way.But it won't be able to crawl pages never linked.

Comment: That's why search engines have 'Submit Your URL' and 'Submit Your Sitemap' pages. Even Google does not crawl pages that are never linked unless it's told about them.

Comment: But some scanning tools can scan out pages never linked.So it's stronger than a general web crawler.

Comment: Not unless there's some known pattern to the URLs such that you can guess at URLs that might exist. There is NO way to 'scan' ALL webpages.